# Is there a Java TThreadPoolServer with NonBlockingSocket in Apache Thrift?

Tags: java, thrift

I have tried TSimpleServer, THsHaServer and TThreadedSelectorSever but none of them worked for my use case where I need to scale. My server needs to receive lots of data but right now when I use the servers listed above the receive rate is 600KB which is very low when compare to other servers which can receive 6MB using one socket. I am bound by thrift and I need to find a way to get through!

Basically I have a service written in C++ and JAVA (same service written in two different languages) and we are trying to see which one has high throughput). with the C++ service we dont use any thrift server. we created our own non blocking server which uses one thread to accept the requests and passes it on to threadpool where the methods gets executed but with the Java service I tried TSimpleServer, THsHaServer and TThreadedSelectorSever and the performance was not great and when I run the profiler the one that seems to hotspot is the following method

```
org.apache.thrift.server.TNonblockingServer$SelectAcceptThread.run() 456
```

I have no idea what is going on underneath the thrift source code.

**Benchmark results:** C++ service 35K/sec(requests per seconds) and Java 2500/sec (request per second) Again they are executing the same methods, same service written in two different languages.

My code for one of the server is as follows. I have tried others as well as mentioned above but no peformance gain

```
        TTransportFactory tTransportFactory  = new TFramedTransport.Factory();
        TNonblockingServerTransport tNonblockingServerTransport = new TNonblockingServerSocket(7911);
        PersistenceService.AsyncProcessor<?> processor = getAsyncProcessor(serviceName);
        Factory protocolFactory = new TBinaryProtocol.Factory(true, true);
        THsHaServer.Args serverArgs = new THsHaServer.Args(tNonblockingServerTransport);
        serverArgs.processor(processor);
        serverArgs.transportFactory(tTransportFactory);
        serverArgs.protocolFactory(protocolFactory);
        TNonblockingServer tNonblockingServer = new THsHaServer(serverArgs);
        System.out.println("Starting persistence server on port 7911 ...");
        tNonblockingServer.serve();
```

Comment: You always have the option to look at other language's bindings and create one from scratch, based on an existing model. Contributions are welcome.

Comment: You need to state why you think a thread-pooled server with non-blocking sockets would be the solution to your problem. Or else don't ask such a specific question.

Comment: I am also ready to share my code in detail if you guys can join me here? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105121/thrift

Comment: So what is the problem with porting your C++ code to Java? Why have you imprisoned yourself within Thrift?